# Delegating single function to client server in python

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I have a simple client-server program using the xml-rpc protocol. My code is presented below. But this does not work as I expect it to. Maybe someone knows why?

In my module `directed_graph` there is function `algorithm_dijkstra(vertex_name)` that I want to execute on the server.

Client:

```py
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy = ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
    # filling the graph with data
    ...
    test = proxy.algorithm_dijkstra(vertex) # I expect the correct data (dictionary) in test after the function is executed on the server
    ...
```

Server:

```py
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from directed_graph import algorithm_dijkstra


def main():
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
    print('Server is listening on port 8080...')
    server.register_function(algorithm_dijkstra)
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Small clarification:
In my module "directed_graph", basically the functions that the client uses, but there is one that I want to perform on the server. I found that if all the functions are performed on the server, then the program works correctly. But how do I delegate only 1 function to the server and not all?

Comment: what error does it throw,add debugging info

Comment: @Maghilvannan, There is no error, but it does not work correctly. For example, I add the edge AB = 5 to the graph, but this edge does not exist after the function works. At the same time, without a client server, everything worked correctly.

Comment: what value does "test" contain if you run your program

Comment: @Maghilvannan, When there was a program without a client server, when adding the edge AB = 5 and passing the algorithm_dijkstra (vertex) parameter vertex = A, the `test` contained the dictionary: {'A': 0, 'B': 5}, that is, from vertex A to vertex A, the minimum distance is 0, and from A to B is 5 (dijkstra algorithm). But with the client server in this case, `test` contains {'A': 'no way'}. That is, the point is specifically in the error when switching to the client-server, and not in my algorithm.

Comment: @Maghilvannan, I clarified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows. On the client, I set and store data for the graph, and on the server I perform only one function `algorithm_dijkstra`. And for everything to work correctly, need to make the second parameter for function `algorithm_dijkstra`, namely transfer the graph itself to this function, and not take the graph from somewhere like me tried to do before. And then everything works correctly and as expected.